# Will I be able to enter France without having booked a return ticket from Europe yet?

Tags: tickets, europe, france, australian-citizens

Going to Europe imminently to study a short tertiary course, half of which will be in France. Haven’t booked my return flight from Germany yet. Will this be a problem for entering Paris?

I have tried to book the flight from the airport in Doha, however despite telling my Australian banks exactly where I was going, my credit cards aren’t working. I don’t have a travel SIM yet and as such cannot receive confirmation messages from either bank, nor call them or indeed anyone else. The wifi here is somewhat functional, but that’s of little consolation.

Comment: You have a student visa I assume?

Comment: No, apparently Australia has a certain visa waiver agreement with the Schengen Zone. I will only be there for 2 weeks, so it’s not a lengthy course.

Comment: You will need to make it believable that you will leave again. An onward ticket helps, but I don't think it is strictly necessary. No ticket and no working credit card could be more difficult. On the plus side, the Schengen area gets relatively few illegal immigrants from Australia, so there will be no instant suspicion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Coming from Australia, no European immigration officer will consider you a particular threat and unless you look or behave suspiciously, chances are close to zero that you will get any question at all at the border.

If you for some reason should be more thoroughly checked, the actual requirement is to have sufficient means to provide for yourself during the intended stay and to leave the Schengen area again. That does not mean that you have to show already booked accomodation or onward transport, but you must strictly speaking be able to show that you have enough money to buy so. If you don't have either a booked accomodation, nor an onward ticket and also currently have problems accessing cash, it might, at least in theory, actually be a problem.

Comment: Wrong, you can be denied entry like is stated at: https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/que-faire-apres-mon-arrivee-en-france
Many Brazilians got denied for not having health insurance or return ticket while they are also waived from applying for a Schengen visa.

Comment: @gstorto Instead of just linking to a page, which is partially self-contradicting, it would be helpful to all if you point out exactly what is wrong in my answer and how my answer is contradicted by anything specific stated on that page.

Comment: @gstorto And that is where the page is contradicting itself. You just have to continue a few paragraphs further before it states correctly, that if you don't have a hotel booking, you must have at least 120€ per day to show that you are able to pay for your expenses: "120 euros per day in the case of non-presentation of a hotel booking;" These entry requirements are set in the Schengen regulations and not in French national law.

Comment: Maybe that the official requirements are: proof of accomodation, health insurance of no less than 30000EUR coverage, proof of funds according minimum amount per day table, return ticket. Another link if you do not like the first one: service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1765

Comment: @gstorto The page you are linking to is also clearly stating that a return ticket is not necessary: "Your return ticket or the financial means to acquire one at the envisaged return date;"

Comment: This explanation is based on law: https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006180217&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158
Which resumes to: whether you get a valid ticket, or a declaration of a financial institution translated to French that guarantees the return of the alien if ever he cannot afford his return. I would bet on the return ticket.

Comment: @gstorto You are not getting more right if we just keep repeating ourselfes. Entry conditions to the Schengen area are defined in EU regulation 2016/399, article 6. Relevant is subsection 1(c) "they have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit to a third country" and subsection 4 "The assessment of sufficient means of subsistence may be based on the cash, travellers’ cheques and credit cards in the third-country national’s possession."

Comment: I, and most other readers here, don't speak French, so it does not do any good if you link to a French page.

Comment: Well, I translated the law for you concerning the means of repatriation. If you don't want to believe in it, I invite you to find its translated version. Immigration is subjected to both national and European laws. Furthermore, your answer does not mention health insurance requirement.

Comment: @gstorto Just as you misquoted the first page you are linking to, I am not sure if you are understanding and translating the French law correctly. It is not my job to find comprehensible proof that you are right if you claim me to be wrong. Entry conditions for *any* country in the Schengen area are set in different EU regulations, from which the member states are not allowed to deviate from with special national provisions, so even if a national French law *should* (I don't say it does) say something else, the EU regulations will have precedence.

Answer (score -2):

To pass French immigration with a Schengen visa or waiver, you need:

- A valid passport issued less than 10 years before and valid for at least 3 months after the envisaged departure date;
- Proof of accommodation covering the whole duration of the stay (hotel reservation and/or certificate of staying with a relative validated in the town hall);
  **However, if you do not present any proof of accommodation, the consequence is that your minimum amount per day will increase.**
- Sufficient financial means. The means of subsistence shall be assessed according to the duration and purpose of the stay and by reference to the average prices for accommodation and food in the Member States;
  For France, this amount (per day) is:

  - 32.50 euros per day if you are hosted by an individual, supposing you presented the certificate of staying validated by the town hall;
  - 65 euros per day of stay in the case of presentation of a hotel booking;
  - 120 euros per day in the case of non-presentation of a hotel booking;
  - In the case of a partial hotel booking: 65 euros per day for the period covered by the booking and 120 euros per day for the remainder of the stay.
- **Your return ticket or the financial means to acquire one at the envisaged return date;**
  Note that the financial means are defined by R211-31 (see link below) as:

  - a declaration of a financial institution translated to French, if not already, that guarantees the return of the alien if ever he cannot afford his return.
- For stays not exceeding 90 days (unless exempt), trips for tourism or business require valid travel insurance covering any possible costs for medical repatriation, and emergency and/or hospital treatment. This is mandatory. This insurance must be valid throughout the Member States’ territory in the Schengen area, which fully apply the provisions of the Schengen accord and for the duration of your stay. It must allow you to access services in the Schengen area. This insurance must also provide coverage of €30,000 minimum including medical repatriation, and emergency and/or hospital treatment.
- Any document providing details on the profession or the capacity of the traveller as well as on the establishments or organisations located in France which are expecting you, if you are on a professional trip.

Sources:

- https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/your-arrival-in-france
- https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1765 (in French)
- https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/faq
- https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006180217&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158 (in French)

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for the downvotes? Everything is backed up by either official French government website or French law.

Comment: Perhaps because that’s not how it works in practice? :)

Comment: @gstorto Which exact part (or parts) of my previous comments do you not understand? You are linking to a web page with several self-contradicting statements and conditions for entry to France are defined in the Schengen regulations and not in French national law.